# Extracting zip file to string location with additional folders

Tags: c#, compression

I am very new to coding and I am having some trouble in extracting a zip file to a directory.

Currently this is my code

```
            string zipPath = "Typhoon.zip";
            string extractPath = str_xp11_loc + @"\Resources\Plugins";
            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
```

When using code above I am getting Invalid characters in path

I have tried code that creates a txt file with the extracting location and adding the "@"\Resources\Plugins" via FileWriter  and that sorta works but only extracts to the first few folders defined. When I use filewriter it creates a new line with "Resources\Plugins" When using this method it extracts to the first line for example C:\Folder1\Output.

I have tried using `string result = Regex.Replace("Xp11_install.txt", @"\r\n?|\n", "");`

to try and remove the the line break but that has not worked.

Is it possible to extract file using the method above?

Any insight is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you are searching for, but in my case I created a ZIP file with a folder and Subfolder inside.

With the following modified code that you provided:

```
    string zipPath = @"YourFilePath.zip";
    string extractPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
```

I was able to extract that file, in this example to the MyPictures folder, with all the Subfolders.
If this is not what you were searching for, maybe have a look at the docs documentation:
[ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.extracttodirectory?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Compression_ZipFile_ExtractToDirectory_System_String_System_String_)